# Fill in the blanks for the cayley tables of the ring $(A,+,\ast)$ where $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm having an issue here, I need to fill in the blanks for a two Cayley, tables, I figured out the first one which is for the operation $+$, which is pretty simple, since for $A$ to be a ring then $(A,+)$ must be an abelian group, therefore it is commutative, and finding which letter goes where is a matter of finding where two letters coincide. However, with the multiplication its not that simple since the proof there requires that multiplication be associative. I'm not so sure how to put that into a table. Here is the table, they told me to fill out with the * operation:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\cdot & a & b & c & d \\\hline
a & a & a  & a & a \\
b & a  & b &   & \\
c & a  &  &   & a \\
d & a &  b & c &   \\ 
\end{array}
$$

So how would I go about filling this out? I'm not entirely sure what it means that a table has an associative property, or how I'd go about identifying it to insert the letters based on that pattern, as I did with the sum operation table. Can anyone help me? I searched for answers, but I couldn't find anything that would help me.

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+ & a & b & c & d \\\hline
a & a & b  & c & d \\
b & b  & a & d & c \\
c & c  & d & a & b \\
d & d &  c & b & a \\ 
\end{array}
$$

That's the adition table, though, I think it is correct given that (A,+) is abelian.

Comment: Does your definition of ring ask for a multiplicative identity?

Comment: @Gamamal It cannot: The table entries $ab = a$, $db = b$, $cd = a$ and (again) $cd = a$ respectively show that each of $a, b, c, d$ cannot be a multiplicative identity.

Comment: @Argus What is the table for $+$?

Comment: A broad hint: keep in mind that multiplication must distribute over addition.  Regardless of which way it distributes, you should have enough information here that you can use that distributive law to flesh out the multiplication table.  For instance, suppose $b+b=c$; then $b\cdot c=b\cdot (b+b)=b\cdot b+b\cdot b=\ldots$; you should be able to use some variant of this whatever the addition table looks like.

Comment: Well that worked, can't I mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

***My working:***

I think associativity will give you most of the gaps

$cb = c(db) = (cd)b = ab = a$

$cc = c(dc) = (cd)c = ac = a$

$bc = (bd)c = b(dc) = ba = a$

$bd = (db)b = d(bb) = db = b$

If you consider $(dd)c = d(dc) = dc = c$ then $dd$ cannot be $a$, $b$ or $c$ and so must be $d$.

So the table becomes

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\cdot & a & b & c & d \\\hline
a & a & a  & a & a \\
b & a  & b &  a & b\\
c & a  & a &  a & a \\
d & a &  b & c &  d \\ 
\end{array}

though I am not totally convinced by the result

Comment: I don't believe this defines a ring. There are two noncommutative rings with additive group $\Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_2$: one has two left identities and the other has two right identities. But the above multiplication table has exactly one left identity and no right identity, and so cannot be either of these.